Question regarding Swift value type thread safety
I have been learning the concept of value types in the swift language. I learned that in swift, each thread will have its own stack, so value types are thread safe in the sense that there is no shared access of the struct among different threads:
here is the code snippet that I seem to struggle understanding:
struct MyStruct {
    let text: String
}

func test() async {
    var myStruct = MyStruct(text: "Hello, World!")//Assume this gets executed on a main thread
    try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))//It will sleep for a sec, and assume this will come back on a background thread
    myStruct = MyStruct(text: "Goodbye, World!")//Being executed on a backgroung thread, and which struct is this actually modifying?
    print(myStruct)//Is it printing the struct exclusive to the background thread?
}

Task {
    await test()
}

in this code snippet, myStruct is a local variable in a function, and because the await keyword can mean that it might come on on a different thread, so if I am modifying the struct then, which struct is it actually modifying? Doesn't the background thread have its own myStruct which is different than the originally created myStruct at the beginning of the function?

This code would have been safe even if MyStruct were a class. There is no concurrency. No two threads can have access to myStruct at the same time. Whichever thread is running var myStruct = MyStruct(text: "Hello, World!") has access to it until await, and after the await some other thread (or the same thread) gains access to it.
Let's see an example where there is concurrency.
class SomeClass {
    var text: String = ""
}

func foo() {
    let instance = SomeClass()
    Task {
        await bar(instance)
    }
    print(instance.text)
}

foo creates an instance of SomeClass, and passing it to bar. bar is called in a top level task which can run concurrently with the rest of foo. Now there is a possibility that bar sets text to something else, at the same time when foo printing instance.text. This is a data race.
If SomeClass were a struct, this is fine because bar(instance) would pass a copy of the struct value, and not a reference.
This is also fine if SomeClass were final, text is a let, and conforms to Sendable:
final class SomeClass: Sendable {
    let text: String = ""
}

As another example, consider
class SomeClass {
    var text: String = ""
}

let someActor = SomeActor()
func foo() async {
    let instance = SomeClass()
    await someActor.bar(instance)
    print(instance.text)
}

actor SomeActor {
    func bar(_ x: SomeClass) {
        // some unknown implementation...
    }
}

Although someActor.bar(instance) doesn't run concurrently with the rest of foo, bar could theoretically store the instance in the actor instance (among other things), and now the actor's executor (which can run concurrently with foo) also has access to it - some other tasks running on the actor could modify instance.text.
Again, if SomeClass were a struct, this will be safe because bar(instance) would pass a copy.

The myStruct variable in your test() function is scoped to that function. When you change it after the await, you are modifying the same local variable, even if it runs on a different thread. Each thread does not have its own separate instance of myStruct; they operate on the same function context, but the value type's nature ensures that if you were to pass it to another context, it would be copied rather than shared.
So, to answer your question directly: the myStruct that you are modifying after the sleep is the same instance (in terms of the function's scope) that was created at the beginning of the function. It does not create a separate instance for the background thread; it simply continues to operate on the local variable in that function.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In your example, you are mutating a locally-isolated myStruct variable, replacing one MyStruct instance with another. But regardless of what threads are being used (more on that below) both the code before and after the await suspension point are isolated to the same actor and are therefore thread-safe. This local variable is not isolated to a particular “thread”, but rather to a particular actor-isolation context.

You are asking us to contemplate a situation where a continuation (the partial task after the await suspension point) runs on a different thread.
A few clarifying observations:

I would encourage you to not think in terms of “threads”. The fact that the continuation might use a different thread is not remotely relevant here. Focus on which isolation context it is running, not on which thread it is running.
While I am going to provide some background, below, of what is going on with threads (in the spirit of WWDC 2021 video Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes), one is best advised to focus on the actor isolation context rather than threads.

Let us first understand the typical manifestation of this optimization (where the continuation runs on a different thread). Consider the following:
actor Foo {
    var isRunning = false

    func foo() async throws {
        isRunning = true         // isolated to Foo; running on thread X
        try await …              // await some asynchronous task    
        isRunning = false        // isolated to Foo; running on thread Y, may be different than X
    }
}

Both X and Y will be threads from the Swift concurrency cooperative thread pool, but they might not be the same thread. But both the work before the await and after the await are isolated to the Foo actor. Thus, there is no race on isRunning even though they are technically running on different threads because the actor enforces a mutual exclusion of execution, regardless of which thread from the cooperative thread pool is being used.

As an aside, the main actor is slightly different. If you are running a partial task that requires isolation, it will always run on the main thread:
@MainActor
final class Bar {
    var isRunning = false

    func bar() async throws {
        isRunning = true         // isolated to main actor; running on main thread
        try await …              // await some asynchronous task    
        isRunning = false        // also isolated to main actor; running on main thread
    }
}

Bottom line, if the code after the await suspension point does anything that requires main-actor-isolation, then it will run on the main thread. (There are some other optimizations that can come into play, but they are not relevant here.)


